# How can I make a dynamic plastic bag?

Tags: modeling, mesh, physics, transparency

I want to make a plastic bag with crumples and appropriate mesh folding, to look something like this: [image]

...and interact realistically with other forces such as force fields, having objects put into it:[image]
...or in my case, folding it around a trash bin:
[image]

So does anyone know how to achieve such result in Blender? Never really seen this be done before :P. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a texture for the folds and bumps in rest position, and maybe a cloth sim to get the physics right for the stretching and key frame the effect of the texture, so that it dissipates at full stretch.

Comment: That doesn't really clarify much, the texture needs to displace, stretch, crumple and generally behave in a **very specific** way. The cloth simulation needs to be perfectly well set for it to work right. That's the thing I was asking an answer for in the first place.

Comment: I've sculpted hires before of the bag I have made and used it to bake a displacement map and normal map to affect the lowpoly model of the bag. I then used physics and cloth sims to get the low poly to stretch and then I keyframed the value of the displacement texture down at the point of full stretch.

Comment: That makes more sense now that I think about it, but if the bag stretched in only one point then turning the whole displacement down wouldn't really work, unless there is a way to tell the value where the stretched points are and where they are not.

Comment: Maybe check this option: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32043/how-does-the-cloth-stiffness-scaling-option-work you could paint randomly to have some stiff parts as folds.

Comment: And you can also use more than one mapped texture and key frame multiple values. Using maybe three textures, you could create more variation altogether.

Comment: Check this one out: Free addon! https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?345542-Addon-Tension-Map

Comment: That could actually be really useful for what I want to achieve, thanks for sharing!